# What's the name of this waterfall?

Tags: identify-this, lock-screens, waterfalls

I found this waterfall scenery during the login screen of Windows 10:

[image]

What's the name of this waterfall ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My bad it seems to be `Bridalveil Fall` in the US. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bridalveil_Fall